# Ignoring second if statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, dev-c++

I'm trying to write a program to calculate the volume and the amount of conditioner to add to fish tanks of either spherical or rectangular shape.

I want it to ask the user if the tank is circular, to which they will answer either 'y', 'Y', or 'n', 'N'.  However, whenever I run the program and enter n or N it still runs the if statement for y or Y.

*Please note that I'm very new to all this.  This is for an intro to programming and logic class.*

Here is my source code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
char Circle = ' ';
int RADIUS = 0;
int HEIcircle = 0;
int LEN = 0;
int WID = 0;
int HEI = 0;
double AMTcondCIR;
double AMTcondREC;
cout << "Is tank circular? ";
cin >> Circle;

if (Circle = 'Y' or 'y')
{

cout << "Enter radius: ";
cin >> RADIUS;
cout << "Enter height: ";
cin >> HEIcircle;
AMTcondCIR = ((4/3) * 3.14 * (RADIUS^3)) * 0.01;
cout << "Amount of Conditioner to add (in mL): " << AMTcondCIR << endl;
}
if (Circle = 'N' or 'n')
{

cout << "Enter length: ";
cin >> LEN;
cout << "Enter width: ";
cin >> WID;
cout << "Enter height: ";
cin >> HEI;
AMTcondREC = (LEN * WID * HEI) * 0.01;
cout << "Amount of Conditioner to add (in mL): " << AMTcondREC << endl;
}
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What book are you learning from? more specifically, what did make you think that your intended comparison works as `if (Circle = 'Y' or 'y')`? You should probably get a higher quality source for learning C++ than you have now

Answer (score 3):

In C++ `=` is assignment operator. For equality, please use `==`.
That is, change

```
if (Circle = 'Y' or 'y')
```

into

```
if (Circle == 'Y' || Circle == 'y')
```

And

```
if (Circle = 'N' or 'n')
```

into

```
if (Circle == 'N' || Circle == 'n')
```

Comment: Also consider using `toupper` or `tolower` to reduce the number of comparisons:  `if (toupper(Circle) == 'N')`.

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement conditions are completely wrong; no part of this does what you think it does: `if (Circle = 'Y' or 'y')`.

You're looking for `if (Circle == 'Y' || Circle == 'y')`. What you've written is wrong for a couple reasons; it's using the assignment operator (`=` instead of `==`), and the other half of the binary `or` is always true.

What you've written is essentially this:

```
if ('Y') {
  if ('y') {

  }
}
```

And 'Y', the character, casts to boolean `true`, just like the character 'N', so both `if` statement's conditions evaluate as true.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `if` statements to

```
if (Circle == 'Y' || Circle == 'y')
...
if (Circle == 'N' || Circle == 'n')
```

Comparison is `==`, whereas assignment is `=`.